# How many yield keywords can be used in function* functions?

Tags: javascript

How many yield keywords can be used in function* functions?

I read this [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield) but not found the answer of above question.

Comment: As many as you want. Why do you think there's a limit?

Comment: @deceze , it is follow by return keyword right?

Comment: Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @chiragsatapara No, it's C# that uses `yield return`. In JavaScript it's just `yield`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have as many as you want. There is no maximum limit to the number of `yield` statements in a generator function.

If you're familiar with C#, then the JavaScript `yield` keyword works similarly to C#s `yield return` statement.

So you can have this:

```
function* returnASequenceOf3Values() {

    yield 1;
    yield 2;
    yield 3;
}
```

Or this:

```
function* returnInfiniteValues() {

    while( true ) {
        yield 1;
    }
}
```

More examples of `yield` (and `yield*`) are given on the `function*` page on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*